# How to grab a certain word from a .txt file given what it begins and ends with

Tags: python, file, parsing, text, tkinter

DISCLAIMER:

I'm using python 3!

FUNDEMENTAL CODE:

So I have this code:

```
def login(userlogin):

    with open('usernames.txt') as input_data: # Grabs username from usernames.txt CHANGE DOESN'T WORK FOR MULTIPLE PEOPLE
        for user in input_data:
            if user.strip() == userlogin:
                break

        for user in input_data:
            if user.strip() == '0':
                break

    print(user)

while(True):
    userinput = input('')
    login(userinput)
```

and also .txt file in the same directory, called usernames.txt which you can see here:

```
admin010
guest020
admin01030
user040
```

DESIRE:

I want the code to output the username corresponding in the .txt file based on the name inputted, so for example, if you inputted `'admin'` it would find text in the text document that starts with `admin` and find its ending which is always a `'0'` and output `admin010`. However, I want it to make sure, when you type `admin01` it would output `admin01030`. So the usernames are in the form, `name + value` (2 digits i.e. a value of 7 would be 07) `+ a zero` (`'0'` string).

PROBLEM:

The code isn't working, no matter my input it always outputs the last word in the .txt document. I'm not sure why, any help would be great.

Comment: please fix the indentation. Select all the text and then click the button on the toolbar that looks like `{}`.

Comment: @Nae I recreated it using the minimal complete and verifiable example, hopefully it helps.

Comment: There's a pretty good chance that this question is a duplicate, but I can't seem to find it.

Comment: @Nae Yeah it works I implemented it into my original project and it works smoothly. Ill remove it from post now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can be written fairly compactly in this way, if I understand you.

```
def login(userlogin):
    with open('usernames.txt') as usernames:
        for line in usernames:
            username = line.strip()
            if username.startswith(userlogin+'0') and len(username)==len(userlogin)+3:
                print (username)
                return
    print ('no match')

for poss in ['admin', 'admin01', 'guest', 'user']:
    print (poss, ': ', end=''); login(poss)
```

Output:

```
admin : admin010
admin01 : admin01030
guest : guest020
user : user040
```

Comment: Oh, I see what you did there. I adjusted it slightly to suit my program, and it's really compact compared to mine. Thank you!

Comment: You're very welcome. Incidentally, I used calls to `print` rather than `return`s because that is what you had in your code. I was trying to make my code parallel to yours.

Comment: @Nae: May very well be so. I haven't tried to make the code bullet-proof, only to make it conform to the specs in the question.

Comment: Yeah I replaced them with returns, and adjusted it a bit so I could implement it onto my original which had this fundamental issue. It's working perfectly now, and there is much less code.

Comment: @Nae what was your input that had an incorrect output? It's not doing that for me, although I did change it slightly.

Comment: @Nae it doesn't for me, i changed for pos in line to for pos in ['a']:, and it outputs no match. That's what I wanted it to do.

Comment: @Imaad My mistake, I think it does work exactly the way you'd want.

Answer (score 1):

If the format is "name + two-digits + 0", then you want to match the name with a line less the last three characters:

```
for user in input_data:
    if userlogin == user.rstrip()[:-3] # strip trailing whitespace and remove last 3 chars
        print(user)
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is basically check if a string has a substring.

In the below example when the button is pressed, it checks if the file `'usernames.txt'` that is in the same directory, has a string that matches exactly the user input before reaching the last 3 letters which are reserved for `value` and `zero`. Then parses it to `name`, `value` and `'0'`:

```
import tkinter as tk

def login():
    with open('usernames.txt') as fin:
        users_list = fin.readlines()

    for user in users_list:
        user = user.strip()             # to lose \n
        if user[:-3] == query.get():
            nam_lbl['text'] = user[:-3]
            val_lbl['text'] = user[-3:-1]
            zero_lbl['text'] = user[-1]

root = tk.Tk()

query = tk.Entry(root)
nam_lbl = tk.Label(root, text="Name: ")
val_lbl = tk.Label(root, text="Value: ")
zero_lbl = tk.Label(root, text="Zero: ")

tk.Button(root, text="Login", command=login).pack()

# layout
query.pack()
nam_lbl.pack()
val_lbl.pack()
zero_lbl.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, I'll test this out but I found a way to do it after all this time, which is completely different to this but this might be better I'll check!

Comment: It didn't really do I wanted it to do, but thanks anyways for all the help. I've got a solution now so it's okay.

Comment: @Imaad How exactly doesn't this do what you want?

Answer (score 0):

Hi please see below code. But I need to know why admin01 would match admin01030 only? since admin010 also starts with admin01

```
def login(userlogin):
    with open(
            'usernames.txt') as input_data:  # Grabs username from usernames.txt CHANGE DOESN'T WORK FOR MULTIPLE PEOPLE
        for user in input_data:
            if user.strip() == '0':
                break
            if user.strip().startswith(userlogin, 0, len(userlogin)):
                break
    print(user)


while True:
    userinput = input('')
    login(userinput)
```

Comment: It wouldn't match as 'admin01' is the name so, to form the username that I'm storing them as, I do name + value + 0. So the name is 'admin01' + a value lets say '004' + '0'. So it would be admin010040.

Comment: But your code works really well, apart from that issue above, I already found a solution but this works really well too and I've edited to fix the issue. Thanks so much!

Comment: This will yield wrong results if the order of lines in `'usernames.txt'` is changed or substring of a line is given such as `'ad'`.